# Cut/copy/paste keyboard shortcuts not working in NSPopover

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, nspopover

I have a macOS `NSPopover` based tray app which shows a popover with login fields (username and password).

Problem is that user is unable to copy-paste his email or password into text fields. The popover doesn't seem to allow keyboard shortcuts for some reason.

Did anyone have similar issues?

Relevant example available here: https://github.com/mixtly87/NSPopoverTest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't the easiest thing to solve and you need to do a few things to get this to work.

1 ) add a MainMenu to your MainMenu.xib file.

Even though the main menu won't display (because you're only doing a NSStatusBar item), you want that main menu because of the command keys in the Edit menu (i.e. something to intercept the <kbd>cmd</kbd>-X, <kbd>cmd</kbd>-C & <kbd>cmd</kbd>-V's).  Those command keys will be sent to your text field or your webview, whatever is the first responder.

[More info can be seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34840587/menu-access-from-nsstatusitem-menu-bar-application-in-swift).

2 )

I made your textfield the first responder by adding:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear
{
    [super viewDidAppear];
    [self.textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

to your ViewController.m file.

3 )

You also need to make the window brought up by the Status Item a key window.  In your example app, you did have a commented out `canBecomeKeyWindow` method.  I uncommented it out and always return `TRUE`.

[More info can be seen here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214273/not-being-able-to-edit-nstextfield-on-nspopover-even-though-editable-behavior-is)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Michael, this was really helpful! In my case though, your solution works even without overriding the `canBecomeKeyWindow` and returning `YES`.